# Why is it so slow DateTime.TryParse with culture US and AdjustToUniversal

Tags: c#

Here's two test, 
first one using :

- **DateTime.TryParse(dateToParse, out date)**

  ```
      var dateToParse = "2012-09-17";

      var startNew = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      for (int i = 0; i < 4059; i++)
      {
          DateTime date;
          if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateToParse, out date))
              continue;


      }
      Console.WriteLine(startNew.GetTimeString());
  ```

**-> Output: 19,1 ms** Lightning fast

second one using:

- **DateTime.TryParse(dateToParse, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out date)**

  ```
      var dateToParse = "2012-09-17";

      var startNew = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      for (int i = 0; i < 4059; i++)
      {
          DateTime date;
          if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateToParse, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out date))
              continue;


      }
      Console.WriteLine(startNew.GetTimeString());
  ```

**-> Output : 11,6 s** really SLOW!!!

Two questions.

1 - Why is it so slow to convert in US culture

2 - What alternative solution can I use to convert a string in datetime with US-Culture

Comment: Move the new CultureInfo call outside the loop. The reason will then be clear.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, In my real implementation code, I'm looping on 4059 objects (financial quotes). Indeed I could have use 4000 for my test but I was too lazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little optimization

```
var dateToParse = "2012-09-17";

CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var startNew = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 4059; i++)
{
    DateTime date;
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateToParse, ci, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out date))
        continue;
}
```

The difference between the first example and the second one is all in that new CultureInfo.
Creating it just one time before entering the loop will drastically reduce the time required.

However I will be curious to see the real performance of the original code when is compiled and executed outside the IDE. It is possible that the JITter will make this optimization by itself.

Comment: thanks Steve, it works. It takes now 12,4 ms. Didn't know that creating a new culture info is so expensive

Comment: @Gui It's not just CultureInfo. You should assume that creating *any* object is expensive. Don't use the `new` keyword any more than you have to!

Comment: `will drastically reduce the time required.` - Confirmative :-) A List with about 19.000 entries is now sorted in a split second, but took ~ 40 seconds, when the `culture-info-creation` was inside the loop... *inserts meme*: "But Why?"

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're creating 4059 objects - specifically in the bit that says `new CultureInfo("en-US")`.

Declare the US `CultureInfo` object outside of the loop.